# PCI - Card Data Transmission

Tags: security, https, pci-dss, pci-compliance

I understand that PCI compliance affects not just storage of card details but does it also affect transmission. E.g.  if I simply want to collect a card number and transmit it over https does this require PCI compliance steps to be taken?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PCI does require protection for card data at rest and in transit, so yes, this will require you to take steps to comply.

This is covered in great detail on [Security Stack Exchange using the PCI-DSS tag.](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pci-dss)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you transfer card data somewhere (no matter - between user browser and your server, between your scripts, between script, database and back, between your server and PayPal / Authorize.net / whatever) - you **must** make all this channels secure.

Say, with SSL layer. Do everything using HTTP**S**, not just simple HTTP and make sure your server's SSL certificate is correct, and up to date.